# achar uma palavra em uma lista de caracteres aleatórios

Tags: python-3.x, lista, algoritmo

preciso de ajuda em nesse exercício em python

Marlon gosta de recortar letras de suas revistas, e depois reorganizá-las para formar frases. Uma vez, ele recortou as letras ZEPUAMAOIZ e percebeu que mudando a ordem das letras, poderia formar a frase EUAMOPIZZA. Como está perto do natal, ele resolveu que iria confeccionar decorações com a palavra NATAL para distribuir para seus amigos! Para isso, Marlon recortou diversas letras de várias revistas diferentes. Mas agora possui uma quantidade enorme de letras embaralhadas, e não sabe quantas palavras NATAL vai conseguir formar com elas!

Ele sabe que você entende de computação, então te pediu para fazer um programa que, dadas as letras embaralhadas, descubra quantas vezes é possível formar a palavra que ele quer. Assim, Marlon saberá quantos amigos ele poderá presentear com as letras que possui!

Input Specification:

A primeira linha de entrada contém um único inteiro N, o número de letras que Marlon possui.

A segunda linha de entrada possui N caracteres do alfabeto, minúsculos, são as letras que Marlon recortou.

Output Specification:

Você deve produzir uma única linha de saída, contendo um inteiro que indica a quantidade de vezes que é possível formar a palavra NATAL com as letras obtidas de entrada.

exemplo:

```
input                             

    9                                      
    
    natalnatl

output

    1
```

eu tentei com esse código que na pratica é funcional mas meio 'gambiara', e o obs: exercício tem o tempo limite de execução do código um segundo

```
a = str(input())

b = a.count('n')
c = a.count('a')
d = a.count('t')
e = a.count('l')

if 5 <= b + c + d + e < 10:
    print(1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

é fácil ver com a conta que você está fazendo que - primeiro, ela não leva em conta que o número de letas pode mudar, segundo, se o input for "nnnnnnnnn" vai resultar em "2".

Tente fazer assim: um programa que pegue conte manualmente as letras - uma por uma, e no final da contagem use a função "min" para saber o mínimo de cada letra que foi lido.

Também é uma boa ocasião para entender como funcionam dicionários em Python, e evitar 26 linhas (ou 26 comandos "if"/"elif") diferentes e o mesmo número de variáveis.

Outra dica legal é fazer o programa não depender da palavra "natal", e poder ser facilmente ajustado para qualquer outra palavra.  (tem uma dificuldade extra por conta de letras duplicadas, como o "a" em "natal", mas aí é que está a graça)